# Is Rust able to optimize local heap allocations?

Tags: rust

When writing relatively realtime code, generally heap allocations in the main execution loop are avoided. So in my experience you allocate all the memory your program needs in an initialization step, and then pass the memory around as needed. A toy example in C might look something like the following:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>

#define LEN 100

void not_realtime() {
    int *v = malloc(LEN * sizeof *v);
    for (int i = 0; i < LEN; i++) {
        v[i] = 1;
    }
    free(v);
}

void realtime(int *v, int len) {
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        v[i] = 1;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    not_realtime();

    int *v = malloc(LEN * sizeof *v);
    realtime(v, LEN);
    free(v);
}
```

And I believe roughly the equivalent in Rust:

```rust
fn possibly_realtime() {
    let mut v = vec![0; 100];
    for i in 0..v.len() {
        v[i] = 1;
    }
}

fn realtime(v: &mut Vec<i32>) {
    for i in 0..v.len() {
        v[i] = 1;
    }
}

fn main() {
    possibly_realtime();

    let mut v: Vec<i32> = vec![0; 100];
    realtime(&mut v);
}
```

What I'm wondering is: is Rust able to optimize `possibly_realtime` such that the local heap allocation of `v` only occurs once and is reused on subsequent calls to `possibly_realtime`? I'm guessing not but maybe there's some magic that makes it possible.

Comment: I would point that `Rust` is a language, so here we are talking about `rustc` (the only available compiler) and more specifically about the LLVM backend behind `rustc` (as `rustc` delegates optimizations to LLVM).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To investigate this, it is useful to add `#[inline(never)]` to your function, then view the [LLVM IR on the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2018&gist=aaa239a13c9601896d6b6de02fee4f3f).

## Rust 1.54

This is **not** optimized. Here's an excerpt:

```
; playground::possibly_realtime
; Function Attrs: noinline nonlazybind uwtable
define internal fastcc void @_ZN10playground17possibly_realtime17h2ab726cd567363f3E() unnamed_addr #0 personality i32 (i32, i32, i64, %"unwind::libunwind::_Unwind_Exception"*, %"unwind::libunwind::_Unwind_Context"*)* @rust_eh_personality {
start:
  %0 = tail call i8* @__rust_alloc_zeroed(i64 400, i64 4) #9, !noalias !8
  %1 = icmp eq i8* %0, null
  br i1 %1, label %bb20.i.i.i.i, label %vector.body
```

Every time that `possibly_realtime` is called, memory is allocated via `__rust_alloc_zeroed`.

## Slightly before Rust 1.0

This is **not** optimized. Here's an excerpt:

```
; Function Attrs: noinline uwtable
define internal fastcc void @_ZN17possibly_realtime20h1a3a159dd4b50685eaaE() unnamed_addr #0 {
entry-block:
  %0 = tail call i8* @je_mallocx(i64 400, i32 0), !noalias !0
  %1 = icmp eq i8* %0, null
  br i1 %1, label %then-block-255-.i.i, label %normal-return2.i
```

Every time that `possibly_realtime` is called, memory is allocated via `je_mallocx`.

#### Editorial

Reusing a buffer is a great way to leak secure information, and I'd encourage you to **avoid it as much as possible**. I'm sure you are already familiar with these problems, but I want to make sure that future searchers make a note.

I also doubt that this "optimization" will be added to Rust, especially not without explicit opt-in by the programmer. There needs to be somewhere that the pointer to the allocated memory could be stored, but there really *isn't* anywhere. That means it would need to be a global or thread-local variable! Rust can run in environments without threads, but a global variable would still preclude recursive calls to this method. All in all, I think that passing the buffer into the method is *much* more explicit about what will happen.

I also assume that your example uses a `Vec` with a fixed size for demo purposes, but if you truly know the size at compile time, a fixed-size array could be a better choice.

Comment: Excellent, thank you. Actually, my security knowledge is quite lacking. That's good to know. In the realtime systems I've worked on (primarily software defined radio), we weren't concerned with security very much, but performance was critical. And yeah the fixed size was for demonstration. A more realistic scenario would involve the size coming from a config file.

Comment: doesn't `#[inline(never)]` break the possibility of the optimization occurring? Rust has malloc optimizations since around a month...

Comment: @ker I dunno about **break**, but perhaps reduce the possibility. I've edited the answer to mention why I think that this "optimization" is unlikely to exist. Can you share some links about the optimizations you are thinking about?

Comment: the relevant PR is https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/22526 . The issue tracking malloc optimizations is https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/22159

Comment: @ker thanks! That looks like it only handles unused calls to malloc. In this case, the allocated space definitely wants to be used (and reused!), so I doubt those would come into play.

Comment: nope, this actually also optimizes malloc -> use -> dealloc to a stack allocation. I thought it also does dealloc -> malloc to noop optimization

Comment: @ker I must be missing something; I don't see any [removal of jemalloc calls](http://is.gd/v1Zb0g). `inline(never)` shouldn't affect optimization *within* a function, right?

Comment: uhm... apparently even the dead allocations don't work anymore: http://is.gd/LWzpqM

Comment: @ker oops! You gonna file an issue?

Answer (score 3):

As of 2021, Rust is capable of optimizing out heap allocation and inlining vtable method calls ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2018&gist=78cf8db61cf6439aca345f2fdf3d0b56)):

```rust
fn old_adder(a: f64) -> Box<dyn Fn(f64)->f64> {
    Box::new(move |x| a + x)
}

#[inline(never)]
fn test() {
    let adder = old_adder(1.);
    assert_eq!(adder(1.), 2.);
}

fn main() {
    test();
}
```